# Are CMake target INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES automatically added to parent INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES?

Tags: cmake

In a directory "fred" that has a CMakeLists.txt that includes :

```
add_library(fred)
...
target_include_directories(fred PUBLIC "inc")
```

This populates the target INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of fred with 'inc'

Does the directory that calls add_subdirectory(fred) automatically get its INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property appended with freds INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property ("inc"), or am I expected to do that manually?

I ask as I have a project that has two add_subdirectory commands, the include paths added by one seem to be available to code, but not the other, not sure if I messed something up or misunderstand!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `the directory .. get its INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property` A directory does not have properties. Targets have properties. Each target has own properties. `am I expected to do that manually?` do what exactly? How would you do that manually? `be available to code [one?], but not the other,` if there are no dependencies between them, then from what you explained this is exactly what should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include directories will be propagated to any target that links to this library. This means add subdirectory is not enough. You also need to have

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> fred)
```

This will add the include directories of fred the MyProject. You can find more information on [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) here.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, that makes a lot of sense...  I studied the help for the commands I was using but not for target_link_libraries.  Although, I still have two sub directories, one that links exactly as you have said, and one that doesn't.  I guess I will have to debug  my cmake files further...